# SnipMate looking in unexpected files for snippets

Tags: vim

I'm editing a PHP file, and when I try to autocomplete something using SnipMate, it gives me two options for which file to load the snippet from: php and *javascript*.

I don't understand why it is trying to load js snippets for a php file. The file extension is `.php`, `filetype` is set to `php`, and `syntax` is set to `php`. How do I tell SnipMate to always load snippets from `php.snippets` for this file?

Comment: Which snipMate version do you use? I've never seen the original plugin asking for what file to load the snippets from.

Comment: I don't see a version anywhere, but `doc/SnipMate.txt` says `Last Change: December 27, 2009`, which seems too old.